# django JSONField doesn't accept value

Tags: python, django

I add a `JSONField` for one of my models. I want to create an instance of that model in admin panel but that `JSONField` returns a validation error (Enter a valid JSON.)

how I can fix this??

model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=500, allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_pic/%Y/%m/%d/', null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    attribute = models.JSONField(default={})
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    discount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    popular = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    comments = GenericRelation(Comment)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I add products in admin panel. I want to have multiple attributes for my products like color , size and ...  . is it true to use json fiels for that??

this is the error:[image]

Comment: You should set `default=dict` not `default={}`, unless you want to share dictionary between all created instances of the same worker. You probably want a new dict each time, which is what `dict` will return when called with no args.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is **not valid JSON**. The strings in JSON are wrapped with *double* quotes. Indeed, you can verify this for example with [*JSONLint.com*](https://jsonlint.com/). It is a valid *Python* dictionary, but not valid JSON.

You thus should enter:

```
{ "key": "value" }
```

For more information, see the [*JSON specifications*](https://www.json.org/json-en.html).

> I add products in admin panel. I want to have multiple attributes for my products like color , size and ... . is it true to use json fiels for that??

If the fields are fixed (are attributes of *all* `Product`s), then you should use individual fields, since that is more convenient to fielter, make forms, etc. If the data is more dynamic, it is often better to make use of a JSON field.

Comment: oh thank you.  i edited my question and asked an important thing about json field usage in my project. please answer that.

Comment: i created a product but the attribute field doesn't shown in out put api. what is the reason??

Comment: @hossein-shahsavan: likely you did not properly serialize it...

Comment: yes i forgot to add that field to serializer. thank you.

Comment: @Williem Van Onsem . could you please take a look at me new question??  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65984415/programmingerror-at-admin-order-order-relation-order-order-does-not-exist-li