# ProgrammingError at /admin/order/order/ relation "order_order" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "order_order"

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with `django rest framework` and I have a app named order. I wanted to change my order logic and I changed order app's models. but when I want to open order and order_item models in admin panel I have this error:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/order/order/
relation "order_order" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "order_order"
```

and also when i run migrate command it doesn't migrate well and doesn't create the order and OrderItem tabels in the database. I'm using postgres db.
there is my code:

models:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    # products = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.full_name

    def total_price(self):
        total = 0
        for order_item in self.products.all():
            total += order_item.get_final_price()
        return total


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.product.name}"

    def get_total_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.price

    def get_total_discount_item_price(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.discount

    def get_amount_saved(self):
        return self.get_total_item_price() - self.get_total_discount_item_price()

    def get_final_price(self):
        if self.product.discount:
            return self.get_total_discount_item_price()
        return self.get_total_item_price()
```

admin:

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user',
                    'ordered',
                    'ordered_date',
                    'created_date',
                    'total_price'

                    ]
    list_display_links = ['user', ]
    list_filter = ['ordered', ]
    search_fields = [
        'user',
        'ref_code'
    ]


admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
admin.site.register(OrderItem)
```

serializers:

```
class OrderItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    final_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderItem
        fields = (
            'id',
            'product',
            'quantity',
            'final_price'
        )

    def get_product(self, obj):
        return ProductSerializer(obj.product).data

    def get_final_price(self, obj):
        return obj.get_final_price()


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = (
            'id',
            'order_items',
            'total',
        )

    def get_order_items(self, obj):
        return OrderItemSerializer(obj.products.all(), many=True).data

    def get_total(self, obj):
        return obj.total_price()
```

Comment: How did you create and apply the migrations?

Comment: python manage.py makemigrations         and     python manage.py migrate

Comment: Is the app configured in the settings?

Comment: @KlausD.yes it worked well but after changes it didn't work

Comment: try this: > python manage.py makemigrations appname > python manage.py migrate appname

Comment: @SivaSankar it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using container platform and using posgres in docker platform. in the posgres container I used a network and storage. because i had an runing container in the storage it was the saved data and I couldn't change them by deleting the db in pgadmin or restarting the containers or changing the db by migration. I removed my containers and made new containers. this way problem fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to comment this, but have you tried using `python manage.py migrate yourapp --fake`?

[Here is where I got it from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555013/django-relation-relation-does-not-exist-cannot-run-python-manage-py-migrate)